# GraphQLRange cannot find a segment that has the cursor

Tags: graphql, relayjs, relay, graphql-js

I'm receiving the following error after a save comment mutation

GraphQLRange cannot find a segment that has the cursor: MTQ2NzkxNTE5NA==

this only happens after I ask for more comments before adding a new one

this is my createContainer code:

```
export default Relay.createContainer(CommentsDetails, {
  initialVariables: {
    count: 10,
  },

  fragments: {
    post: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on Post {
        id,
        comments(first: $count) {
          edges {
            cursor,
            node {
              createdAt,
              ${Comment.getFragment('comment')},
            }
          },
          pageInfo {
            hasNextPage,
            hasPreviousPage,
            startCursor,
            endCursor,
          },
        }
      },
    `,
  },
});
```

this is my save comment mutation

```
import Relay from 'react-relay';

export default class SaveCommentMutation extends Relay.Mutation {
  getMutation() {
    return Relay.QL `mutation {
      saveComment
    }`;
  }

  getVariables() {
    const { post, body } = this.props;
    console.log('variables: ', post, body, this.props);
    return {
      post_id: post.id,
      body,
    }
  }

  getFatQuery() {
    return Relay.QL`
      fragment on saveCommentPayload {
        commentEdge,
        post {
          id,
          comments,
        },
        error,
      }
    `;
  }
  getConfigs() {
    return [
      {
        type: 'FIELDS_CHANGE',
        fieldIDs: {
          post: this.props.post.id,
        },
      },
      {
        type: 'RANGE_ADD',
        parentName: 'post',
        parentID: this.props.post.id,
        connectionName: 'comments',
        edgeName: 'commentEdge',
        rangeBehaviors: {
          '': 'append',
          'orderby(createdAt)': 'append',
      },
    }];
  }

  getOptimisticResponse() {
    const { post, body } = this.props;

    return {
      post: {
        id: post.id,
      },
      commentEdge: {
        node: {
          body: body,
          createdAt: new Date().toUTCString(),
          user: {
            name: 'anonymous',
          }
        }
      }
    };
  }
}
```

this is the generated graphql query, it works if I try on graphql

```
mutation SaveCommentMutation($input_0:saveCommentInput!) {
  saveComment(input:$input_0) {
    clientMutationId,
    ...F5,
    ...F6
  }
}
fragment F0 on Post {
  id
}
fragment F1 on Comment {
  id,
  body,
  createdAt,
  user {
    username,
    name,
    id
  }
}
fragment F2 on Post {
  id,
  _comments2g8zcs:comments(first:10) {
    edges {
      cursor,
      node {
        createdAt,
        id,
        ...F1
      }
    },
    pageInfo {
      hasNextPage,
      hasPreviousPage,
      startCursor,
      endCursor
    }
  }
}
fragment F3 on Post {
  id,
  _comments3Cdb4n:comments(after:"MTQ2NzkyMDExNQ==",first:10) {
    edges {
      cursor,
      node {
        createdAt,
        id,
        ...F1
      }
    },
    pageInfo {
      hasNextPage,
      hasPreviousPage,
      startCursor,
      endCursor
    }
  }
}
fragment F4 on Post {
  id,
  _comments1Z6zk7:comments(after:"MTQ2NzkxNTE5NA==",first:10) {
    edges {
      cursor,
      node {
        createdAt,
        id,
        ...F1
      }
    },
    pageInfo {
      hasNextPage,
      hasPreviousPage,
      startCursor,
      endCursor
    }
  }
}
fragment F5 on saveCommentPayload {
  post {
    id,
    ...F0,
    id,
    id,
    ...F2,
    ...F3,
    ...F4
  }
}
fragment F6 on saveCommentPayload {
  commentEdge {
    cursor,
    __typename,
    node {
      createdAt,
      id,
      body,
      user {
        username,
        name,
        id
      }
    }
  },
  post {
    id,
    ...F0,
    id,
    id
  }
}
```

I think this happens because it cannot find the right list of comments that it should append the new created comment